# Install sys package: "ERROR: No matching distribution found for sys"

Tags: python-3.7, python-idle, sys

I am trying to install `sys` package in Python 3.7.4 version using IDLE:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Downloads>pip install sys
```

I am getting the following error:

> Collecting sys
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sys (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for sys

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the `pip install` command. `sys` is part of the standard library, so it is built into Python that you installed. Use `import sys` in your `.py` file and run it to see exactly which libraries are giving you the import error.